# How to upload a file from different directories other than my root directory and why am I required to attach a file?

Tags: php, attachment, swiftmailer

I'm developing a mailing system using PHP and Swiftmailer: Take a look at my scripts:

// **HTML Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">

<label>Sender's Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" tabindex="1" placeholder="Sender's Email" required/>

<label>Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter Email Subject" required />

<label>Attach File:</label>
<input type="file" name="attach" tabindex="3" value=" " />

<label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="message" tabindex="4" placeholder="Enter Message" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" />

</form>
```

// **Mailer.php  --> Message Part of the email**

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

->setSubject($_POST['subject'])

->setFrom($_POST['email'])

->setBody('<em>' . $_POST['message'] . '!</em>', 'text/html')

->addPart('Here is the message in plain text!', 'text/plain');

$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_POST['attach']));

$mailer->batchSend($message);`
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My 2 issues are:

**1. When I upload files from a different directory other than my root directory, it gives me this error:**

> Warning: fopen(.open child's locket.jpg): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php
>   on line 125   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with
>   message 'Unable to open file for reading [.open child's locket.jpg]'
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php:126
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php(75): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\Base64ContentEncoder.php(34):
>   Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8190) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(500):
>   Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder->encodeByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream),
>   Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer), 0, 78) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(517):
>   Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->toByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer))
>   '#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\ in C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php
>   on line 126

**2. When I dont attach a file (which I should allow a user to do so), it gives me this error:**

> Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php
>   on line 125   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with
>   message 'Unable to open file for reading []' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php:126
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php(75): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\Base64ContentEncoder.php(34):
>   Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8190) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(500):
>   Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder->encodeByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream),
>   Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer), 0, 78) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(517):
>   Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->toByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer))
>   '#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\S
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MailerProject_Test\SwiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php
>   on line 126

Comment: #1. PHP likely doesn't have access to that folder. #2. Don't try to attach a file if you don't intend to attach a file.

Comment: Hi databyss, Thanks. for point 1, once I upload this online, the sender should be able to attach whatever files needed to be attached, so most likely, the sender will be accessing different folders outside the bounds of my root folder. and for point 2, of course there will be that option for the sender to either attach a file or not. So the file upload part should remain there though the sender might not use it. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I found the Answer for number 2:
Just added the following condition:

    if(isset($_POST['attach']) != '')
{
 $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_POST['attach']));
}

This will allow the message to attach a file it the sender attached a file, and leave it if the sender doesnt attach any file. I missed this in writing my script.

I only need help in number 1 where I need to attach files from different locations.

Thank you.

Comment: Okay.. I finally solved the issue!! :D